# How can we track user engagement per custom event?

Tags: google-analytics

We have a flutter app that is using firebase analytics to log custom events with custom parameters like "device_name". Now in the google analytics explore page, we set the device_name as the column and User engagement as the values. Device names are showing correctly but with 0 days of user engagement. How can we track user engagement per custom event?

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, you may have to debug the events in the firebase analytics console; there is probably an issue there. But if not you can use Custom Reports using the same setup as the original method. Using device_names as the custom parameter and User engagement as the value or metric to get the same data. Below I have articles to debug events if that is the issue.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview